# Laplace transform of $e^{-at}$: Using analytic continuation to get a bigger ROC

Tags: convergence-divergence, solution-verification, laplace-transform, fake-proofs

I am having some problem to understand Convergence regions. Where is the error of following thought? Thank you in advance for some light!

I want to calculate Laplace Transform of $e^{-at}$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$, what I know that is $\dfrac{1}{s+a}$ for $\text{Re}(s)>-a$.

Writing exponential in series:

$$e^{-at}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{a^k}{k!}.$$

So,

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st}e^{-at} dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \dfrac{(-a)^k}{k!}\int_0^\infty t^ke^{-st}dt.$$

But $$\Gamma(k+1)=k!=\int_0^\infty t^ke^{-t} dt,$$ with $x>0.$

Then, for $\text{Re}(s)>0$ (*) and doing $t\to st$,
$$k!=s^{k+1}\int_0^\infty t^ke^{-st} dt.$$

So,
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st}e^{-at} dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \dfrac{(-a)^k}{k!}\dfrac{k!}{s^{k+1}}=\dfrac{1}{s}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg(-\dfrac{a}{s}\bigg)^k.$$

But this converges iff $\bigg\vert-\dfrac{a}{s}\bigg\vert<1$, ie, $\text{Re}(s)>a$.

Why did I not get $\text{Re}(s)>0$, since I've considered $\text{Re}(s)>0$ in (*) and the true convergence region is $\text{Re}(s)>-a$?

For instante, let be $a=1$ and $s=0.5$. So, the geometric series really diverges! But the Laplace Transform converges... So, what is the fail on the "iff"...?

***---------------------***

EDIT: Gary said on comments: *"You can appeal to analytic continuation to extend the result to a larger domain."*

***Although this was not the main objective of the question that day, now if you could post an answer or an example indication of how to use analytic continuation in this specific case, I would be very grateful.***

Comment: You can appeal to analytic continuation to extend the result to a larger domain.

Comment: Another way to get the Laplace transform is to assume first that $s+a>0$. Then $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - st} e^{ - at} dt}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - (s + a)t} dt}  = \frac{1}{{s + a}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - u} du}  = \frac{1}{{s + a}}.
$$ Now, by analytic continuation, the result holds when $\Re (s) +a >0$, i.e., $\Re(s)>-a$.

Comment: @Gary thank you so much. I am really stucked to find the problem on the argument on the following sense: For instante, let be $a=1$ and $s=0.5$. So, the geometric series really diverges! But the Laplace Transform converges... So, what is the fail on the "iff"...? Sorry if I can't explain it better... Thank you so much!

Comment: You integrated a series term-by-term which is not allowed in general.

Comment: Hummm Thank you so much @Gary, I thought that is relation with https://www.macalester.edu/aratra/chapt1/chapt1_5.html...

Comment: The problem is that you integrated on an infinite domain here. Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489080/swapping-an-improper-integral-and-series

Comment: @Gary thank you

Comment: @Gary "You can appeal to analytic continuation to extend the result to a larger domain."

Although this was not the main objective of the question that day, now if you could post an answer or an example indication of how to use analytic continuation in this specific case, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You obtained the result for $s>a$, say. The function $s \mapsto 1/(s+a)$ is analytic for $\Re s>-a$, and the function $$
s \mapsto \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - st} e^{ - at} dt} 
$$ is also analytic  for $\Re s>-a$. You showed that they agree on $s>a$. By the principle of analytic continuation (or uniqueness theorem of analytic functions) they must agree on the larger domain $\Re s>-a$ as well.

Comment: @Gary Yes, perfect! Thank you. One more question if you do not matter: if the REAL poles of the function $F(s)$ allows a domain $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ where $F(s)$ is analytic and the function has Laplace Transform on $S$, say $s>s_0$, and they are equal on $D\subset S$, can I use the uniqueness theorem also only on this REAL domain to prove that $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=F(s)$?  (I mean, maybe there's poles of $F(s)$ with $\Re(s)>s_0$, but I am interested only on the real line). If you want and can, you can join your comments into a solution and I will be grateful to reward you.

Comment: If both the Laplace transform integral and the resulting explicit function are analytic on a domain $S$, and you obtained their equality on $D$ (which is at least a set of points having a limit point in $S$) then they must be equal on $S$ as well.

Comment: @Gary Thank you so much. I'd like to bounty you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtained the result for $s>a$, say. The function $s↦1/(s+a)$ is analytic for $\Re s>−a$, and the function
$$s↦∫_0^{+∞} e^{−st}e^{−at} dt$$
is also analytic for $\Re s>−a$. You showed that they agree on $s>a$. Since $\left\{ {s:s > a} \right\}$ is a subdomain of $\left\{ {s:\Re s > -a} \right\}$, by the principle of analytic continuation (or uniqueness theorem of analytic functions) they must agree on the larger domain $\Re s>−a$ as well.